# ORDER BY two columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a pretty complex query I'm using to pull some results from a database (the DB design is quite dirty).

Basically the final result I'm trying to order by two criterion:

1. `t.property`
2. `l.unit_number`

Basically I want all the like `t.property`'s to be grouped, and then the `l.unit_number` to sort based on what I have pre-existing.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  t.name_first,
        t.name_middle,
        t.name_last,
        t.tenant_id,
        t.property,
        l.unit_number
FROM tenants t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  tenant_id, property, unit_number,
            max(lease_start_date) AS newest_start_date
    FROM leases
    GROUP BY property, unit_number
) x
ON t.tenant_id = x.tenant_id
INNER JOIN leases l
ON l.lease_start_date = x.newest_start_date
AND l.tenant_id = t.tenant_id
WHERE t.name_first != 'Pending'
AND l.termination_date IS NULL
ORDER BY l.unit_number REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+$'
        ,CAST(l.unit_number as SIGNED INTEGER)
        ,CAST(REPLACE(l.unit_number,'-','')AS SIGNED INTEGER)
        ,l.unit_number
        ,t.property
```

Currently my data is sorting appropriately based on the `l.unit_number` criterion, but not the `t.property`, ie:

```
t.property      l.unit_number
4321 Test       1
1234 Test       2
5555 Test       3
4321 Test       4
1234 Test       7320-1
4321 Test       7320-2
5555 Test       7320-3
5555 Test       7320-4
1234 Test       A
4321 Test       B
4321 Test       C
5555 Test       D
```

Ideally I'd like the output to be grouped by `t.property` and then sorted by `l.unit_number`. Ie:

```
t.property      l.unit_number
1234 Test       2
1234 Test       7320-1
1234 Test       A
4321 Test       1
4321 Test       4
4321 Test       7320-2
4321 Test       B
5555 Test       3
5555 Test       7320-3
5555 Test       7320-4
5555 Test       D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put t.property at the beginning of your `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY t.property
    ,l.unit_number REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+$'
    ,CAST(l.unit_number as SIGNED INTEGER)
    ,CAST(REPLACE(l.unit_number,'-','')AS SIGNED INTEGER)
    ,l.unit_number
```

Comment: Ha. Yeah this works. I tried it before and didn't realize I didn't put a comma after the t.property. Such a dolt. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is it any more complicated than just this?

```
ORDER BY t.property
        ,l.unit_number
```

Comment: I think you want t.property first.  The other lines all relate to unit_number.